# how to pass decorated function arguments in decorator

Tags: python, newrelic, python-decorators

I have code below

```
@newrelic.agent.data_store_trace('Mysql', '<name>',None)
def get_user(request=None, name=settings.DEFAULT_NAME):
    # Some implementation
```

In the decorator, in place of `<name>` I want to pass name which is in the decorated function.

Note that I don't want to modify/override the decorator as newrelic updates the packages time-to-time, It would be a problem for us.

Any solution???

Answer (score 0):

Decorators are simply wrapper functions.

Write another wrapper function that wraps `newrelic.agent.data_store_trace` and allows to pass a name.

Say New Relic defines `data_store_trace` as:

```
import functools


def data_store_trace(product, target, operation):
  def wraps(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      print('Tracing: ', fn.__name__, args, kwargs)
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
  return wraps
```

Adding another level of indirection will give:

```
def data_store_trace_with_name(product, operation, target=''):
  def wraps(fn):
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      return data_store_trace(product, target, operation)(fn)(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
  return wraps

@data_store_trace_with_name('Mysql', None, '<name>')
def add(x, y):
  return x + y

add(5, 6)
```